# How to build a dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build an Ender pearl dispenser that gives me a specific amount of pearls if i step on a pressure plate.

How do I do that?

Comment: I would recommend rewording your question to ask how to dispense a certain number of items not how to find tutorials since I suspect people will view that as off topic and try to close your question.

Comment: Actually, [this would be a better one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173409/how-can-i-make-the-redstone-repeat-a-task-x-times-and-reset-it-self).

Comment: To be fair, I don't think this is a dupe for the simple fact he also needed to know how to build a dispenser

Answer (score 1):

This video is a very quick tutorial on how to build an "Ender Station". This will dispense 16 Ender Pearls with each press of the button.

Unfortuantely, there's not much about how it works exactly, but from a basic understanding of it, the system uses a combination of powering Redstone torches, combined with a delayed loop (using a repeater), to dispense 8 items, from 2 dispensers, giving you 16 Ender Pearls*.

This is a very old version, (the video was posted back in 2013), however there is nothing about the mechanics that would not allow it to work in current versions.

As for how to build all the components in this module, you can find all the recipes on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone#Crafting_ingredient).

---

*This only dispenses 16 - no more, and no less. But, outside of commands, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: I have messed with these and this is the only way besides commands to dispense ender pearls but you can only do them by 8 ender pearls per dispenser, but this is the only way to do it with dispensers.

Answer (score 0):

You could've just looked on the Minecraft Wiki, but I won't judge.

Here's the recipe on how to make one:

[image]

For some items such as potions, water buckets, fire charges, and arrows, The dispenser will throw, place and shoot, but not drop the item. If you want to do this, you need a dropper:

[image]

I hope this was helpful. Happy crafting!

Comment: While what you said is true, he wants it to throw a specific number of pearls. That just throws one pearl (or other objects)

Comment: ah, I see. Sorry about that, Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can always use command blocks type in chat:

> /give @p minecraft:command_block

Then you place it under were you are going to have the pressure plate then go into it and type:

> /give @p minecraft:ender_pearl 16

Then put the pressure plate on it and all you have to do is change the last number to how many ender pearls you want it to give you.